# How do I loop a set of functions over and over for a vertical news ticker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I am trying to create a vertical latest news ticker, and am very new to javascript, but I wish to learn and create myself.

I have created this so far, but want the news to restart the loop once completed.

```js
    var latestNews = "February 2021 - Latest News for Feb";
    var latestNews2 = "January 2021 - Latest News for Jan";
    var latestNews3 = "December 2020 - Latest News for Dec";
    var latestNews4 = "November 2020 - Latest News for Nov";
    var latestNews5 = "October 2020 - Latest News for Oct";
    latestNewsFunction()

    function latestNewsFunction() {
        document.getElementById("latestNews").innerHTML = latestNews;
        document.getElementById("latestNews2").innerHTML = latestNews2;
        document.getElementById("latestNews3").innerHTML = latestNews3;
        document.getElementById("latestNews4").innerHTML = latestNews4;
        document.getElementById("latestNews5").innerHTML = latestNews5;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('latestNews').className += ' hidden';
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('latestNews2').className += ' hidden';
    }, 6000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('latestNews3').className += ' hidden';
    }, 9000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('latestNews4').className += ' hidden';
    }, 12000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('latestNews5').className += ' hidden';
    }, 15000);
```

```css
    .ln-container {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        height: 33px;
    }
    .lnln {
        list-style-type: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0;
        height: 14px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Latest News Ticker</title>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="ln-container"><b><u>Latest News</u></b>
    <ul class="lnln">
        <li id = "latestNews"></li>
        <li id = "latestNews2"></li>
        <li id = "latestNews3"></li>
        <li id = "latestNews4"></li>
        <li id = "latestNews5"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would very much appreciate it. I am rather new to javascript, so it is all rather crude at the moment, but with practice I intend to improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your news in an array and just have 1 element which you update in a repeating cycle:

```js
var latestNews = [
  "February 2021 - Latest News for Feb",
  "January 2021 - Latest News for Jan",
  "December 2020 - Latest News for Dec",
  "November 2020 - Latest News for Nov",
  "October 2020 - Latest News for Oct"
]
latestNewsFunction()

function latestNewsFunction() {
  let i = 0;
  setNews(latestNews[i])
  setInterval(() => setNews(latestNews[++i % latestNews.length]), 3000)
}

function setNews(news) {
  document.getElementById("latestNews").innerHTML = news;
}
```

```css
.ln-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 33px;
}

.lnln {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ln-container"><b><u>Latest News</u></b>
  <ul class="lnln">
    <li id="latestNews"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. If you want to stop it, you can combine a clearTimeout and if statement. Setinterval allows it to loop every 3 seconds.
I'm also semi-new to javascript so their may be a better solution. Enjoy!

```html
    <div class="ln-container"><b><u>Latest News</u></b>
        <ul class="lnln">
            <li id = "latestNews">February 2021 - Latest News for Feb</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<script>   
    var news = {
        1: "February 2021 - Latest News for Feb",
        2: "January 2021 - Latest News for Jan",
        3: "December 2020 - Latest News for Dec",
        4: "November 2020 - Latest News for Nov",
        5: "October 2020 - Latest News for Oct",
    }
    latestNewsFunction()

    function latestNewsFunction() {
        // Start counter at 2 as the first is already displayed.
        var i = 2;
        setInterval(() => {
            document.querySelector("#latestNews").innerHTML = news[i];
            i++;
            // If on last news, reset
            if (i > 5) {
                i=1;
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```